# How can I generate a keyboard macro in my Emacs init file?

Tags: emacs, macros

I am defining a particular keyboard macro quite often, so I thought that it might be handy if it was automatically available every time I load Emacs.

How can I do this?

Comment: Write a corresponding elisp function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the [save keyboard macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html) section of the manual?

```
C-x C-k n
    Give a command name (for the duration of the Emacs session) to the most recently defined keyboard macro (kmacro-name-last-macro).
C-x C-k b
    Bind the most recently defined keyboard macro to a key sequence (for the duration of the session) (kmacro-bind-to-key).
M-x insert-kbd-macro
    Insert in the buffer a keyboard macro's definition, as Lisp code.
```

Comment: yep, I already done that. but I want to persist the macro even after I restart emacs.

Comment: That's what `insert-kbd-macro` does: "To save a kbd macro, visit a file of Lisp code such as your `~/.emacs', use this command, and then save the file."

Comment: The manual section referenced talks specifically about saving recorded macros to your init file.

Comment: use `global-set-key` to bind your named macro to a key.

Answer (score 0):

This is largely a duplicate of the accepted answer, but I highly recommend [this Mastering Emacs article](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/keyboard-macros-are-misunderstood).

If you know the key sequence in the appropriate format, you can go directly to using `defalias` and `kmacro` -- for example, to do `C-c a a`, just put this in your init file:

```
 (defalias 'start-org-agenda
    (kmacro "C-c a a") "Start the org-mode agenda for the current day.")
```