# Emacs : I get an "No Match" error when I try to save a numerically named macro to the init file

Tags: emacs, macros

I did search other post but to no avail.

With <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> `NameOfMacro`, I can define my macro to a name (ddd for Delete DD tags) and reuse it at will with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ddd` ... np.

I then open my .emacs in another buffer and use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> `ddd` <kbd>RET</kbd> to insert the lambda code to it. Works just fine.

I also used <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to assign it to a single number, like the Emacs manual shows: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> (I chose 4 because "d" is the fourth letter). I can then reuse it at will with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>.

Back to my .emacs buffer and go <kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` and give the single number "4" and it gives me a "No Match" error. Weird because I can actually use the <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> macro in the .emacs buffer. I deduced that `insert-kbd-macro` is the wrong command to save single numerical digit named macro.

But at the end of 21.5 in the manual it says:

> "If you give `insert-kbd-macro` a numeric argument, it makes additional Lisp code to record the keys (if any) that you have bound to macro name, so that the macro will be reassigned the same keys when you load the file."

I don't understand...

seh, angus... your wisdom please.
Thanks to all who responds.

P.S. I think that my question is the last post in the following:
[How can I generate a keyboard macro in my Emacs init file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278375/how-can-i-generate-a-keyboard-macro-in-my-emacs-init-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mis-understanding the instruction to "give ... a numeric argument".

Interactively, that means use a numeric *prefix argument*. So any of these would suffice:

- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-1</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-9</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You were trying to enter the number as the macro name, which is why it couldn't find a match (your macro name was `ddd`).

Answer (score 0):

Note kmacro-name-last-macro (C-x C-k n) assigns a **name** to the last macro.

Then insert-kbd-macro inserts into your buffer the macro of the given **name**.

What is not compatible is kmacro-bind-to-key (C-x C-k b) which binds the last macro to a **key** (not a name).

Comment: So there is no possibility to save to the init file a macro that was named with (C-x C-k n).
Some limitation, np.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacrosTricks - see "I use the following code to automate the process"

Comment: Neeeeeet !
Just added it to my .emacs
Thanks my friend.